# parameterized query Postgres for sql injection mitigation

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-injection, psycopg2, python-db-api

```
stmt = "SELECT filecontent FROM filecontent WHERE filecontent_id = %d AND filecontent LIKE '%% %s %%'"%(int(result_file_pri[0]),str(myjson['recordType']))
curs.execute(stmt)
```

Trying to conevert above postgres query to parameterized query to itigate sql injection. The solution I found on internet is to include stmt in execute statement and take %s out of quotes i.e

```
curs.execute("SELECT filecontent FROM filecontent WHERE filecontent_id = %s AND filecontent LIKE %% %s %%",(int(result_file_pri[0]),str(myjson['recordType'])))
```

The above doesn't work for %% %s %% for me, how do I rectify the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the parameter that holds the percent character:

```
curs.execute("SELECT filecontent FROM filecontent WHERE filecontent_id = %s AND filecontent LIKE %s",
             (int(result_file_pri[0]), str("%" + myjson['recordType'] + "%")))
                                            ^----------------------------^
                                                    so the wildcard is the
                                                     part of the parameter
```